# Twitter Bootstrap - What files do I need to download?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm new to Twitter Bootstrap. 
I'm trying to rebuild the "getting-started" site from here to find out how everything works: 
http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/getting-started.html

I downloaded the Bootstrap package but the header image is missing and the navigation on the left is not fixed. (It scrolls with the rest)

What do I need to download - Is there a .JS file missing?

Answer (score 0):

A great way to see which files a website uses is by using the Chrome Inspector. Open it up on a webpage with Menu > Tools > Developer Tools. Click on the "Resources" tab to see which files the webpage uses. Note that not all web pages are static files. Some are dynamically generated.

If you want access to the entire site's source, it's available at https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/tree/gh-pages

Answer (score 0):

The zip file has everything you need to get started. For more details, you can clone the git, and check the example folder. There are a few .js for each of the features listed in the guide.

Comment: How can I download the bootstrap site itself? http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/ I like they layout and functions of it. It would be good way to start customize it. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Anky: Just updated my answer with a link to the source code. You can run `git clone https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/tree/gh-pages` to get a copy of the repository.